# How to use "considering [that]" as a conjunction?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, sentence-structure

How do I use the conjunction "considering [that]" in Chinese? See example below.

> "The companies process is sub-optimal, **considering** the complexity of their business model."

Comment: see dictionaries, iciba: considering CONJ-SUBORD 考虑到(后接从句) Considering that you are no longer involved with this man, your response is a little extreme.

考虑到你已经与这个男人划清了界限，你的反应有一点儿过头。
also 由于; 鉴于, users suggest putting the subordinate clause in front as in above examle

Answer (score 1):

考虑到，as has been pointed in another answer. If you want to sound a bit more bookish, perhaps 鉴于，eg.

> 鉴于他已改正错误, 你就原谅他吧。  Considering he has already corrected his mistake,
>   you really should forgive him.

Answer (score 0):

"The companies process is sub-optimal, considering the complexity of their business model."

I am not sure exactly what a 'companies process' is. Maybe you meant 'the company's processing method'? If you mean various companies, I don't think they would have 1 process and 1 business model.

Considering the complexity of its business model，
考虑到其业务模式的复杂性，
the company's processing method is sub-optimal.
该公司的处理方法不合适。